# Delete an image in OpenCV using Python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to open and save an image in the local folder using cv2.imread and cv2.imwrite in OpenCV using Python. I want that the next time I run the code the previously saved images should be deleted. Is there any method in OpenCV which can delete an image from the specified folder. Please note that I want to delete the image, not overwrite on it.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use Python to clean up your local folder?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
import os
try: 
    os.remove("my.png")
except: pass
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use os.remove(imagePath) to delete the image

```
import os
try: 
    os.remove(imagePath)
except: pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple as below

```
import os
try: 
    os.remove("Path/of/the/image")
except: pass
```